# Why is ordering ignored when creating view for PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-view

I have a PostgreSQL (version 12.15) database with a table like this:

| id | created_at | number | chat_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | 2023-08-10 21:44:19.272299 | 0 | 27936 |
| ... | 2023-08-09 10:32:28.850167 | 0 | 27936 |
| ... | 2023-08-08 17:32:11.207523 | 0 | 27936 |
| ... | 2023-08-07 17:16:52.068309 | 0 | 27936 |
| ... | 2023-08-06 17:15:47.014364 | 0 | 27936 |

This result was received from a query

```
SELECT * 
FROM _table_name 
WHERE chat_id = '27936' 
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

To put down the value of `number`, I execute the following queries:

```sql
CREATE VIEW view_message 
AS 
    SELECT * 
    FROM _message 
    ORDER BY created_at;

CREATE RULE rule_message AS ON UPDATE TO view_message
    DO INSTEAD UPDATE _message SET number = NEW.number WHERE id = NEW.id;

UPDATE view_message
SET number = create_sequence_number(chat_id::text);
```

But after it I run

```
SELECT * 
FROM _table_name 
WHERE chat_id = '27936' 
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

again, I get an output like this (`number` values are wrong):

| id | created_at | number | chat_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | 2023-08-10 21:44:19.272299 | 83 | 27936 |
| ... | 2023-08-09 10:32:28.850167 | 82 | 27936 |
| ... | 2023-08-08 17:32:11.207523 | 33 | 27936 |
| ... | 2023-08-07 17:16:52.068309 | 82 | 27936 |
| ... | 2023-08-06 17:15:47.014364 | 120 | 27936 |

`number` was to be maxed out for the topmost line and decremented by one for each successive.

It seems that `ORDER BY created_at` was not taken into account when creating view. But still I do not understand what exactly happened and why the error happened.

---

`create_sequence_number` is the function that generates a sequence number depending on the passed id value.

Comment: that resulting table looks right?

Comment: Tables are always unordered. If order is needed it needs to be specified in the SQL that is being submitted.

Comment: For your second result set are you selecting from the view or the table? If from the table the result will not be ordered unless you use an `order by`.

Comment: Because views (as well as tables) do not have ordering in relational databases. PostgreSQL accepts the `ORDER BY` clause but silently ignores it. IMHO it should not even accept this clause in a view definition.

Comment: @TheImpaler that is, my assumption that the order is ignored when creating a view, correct?

Comment: @TheImpaler, that is not true for the Postgres 14 & 15 instances I just tested on. The `order by` is honored.

Comment: The point is that the order is not guaranteed unless you include an ORDER BY clause. For example, querying a table normal returns records in PK order - but you can’t rely on this if the order is important to you

Comment: @NickW But after all, the view was created on query with the presence of `ORDER BY`. When requesting from a view, shouldn't the order be guaranteed?

Comment: NO - the order is not guaranteed, a view is a table expression which returns a derived table, the fact an order by was included is irrelevant (and some DBMS rightly only allow it where it's required for filtering ie when reatricting the rows based on an order), this is a fundamental property of a set; if you require a specific order you must specify it in the outer query, understanding this is *cruicial* to working with sets.

Comment: @Stu that is not correct, see my answer. Try it for yourself.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver no, that is correct and a fundamental part of set theory; with such a small data set you are unlikley to have any issues however with larger result sets, on a busy high concurrency server, the DBMS is not obliged to return any specific order unless specified in the outer query, assuming anything else is a [bug waiting to happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282826/does-order-by-in-view-guarantee-order-of-select)

Comment: The issue is your `create_sequence_number` is generating the `number` from another table that is not controlled by the `ORDER BY created_at`. The chances that it would line up with the view order is slim to none.

Comment: @Stu see my **UPDATE** to answer and then demonstrate when `order by` is not used.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver you seem to be missing the point that the order is not guaranteed unless you use an ORDER BY clause. You could test it a million times and get the order you expect but there is no guarantee that the next query still be ordered. In SQL, if you want to guarantee the order that records are returned in a query you have to use an ORDER BY

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually update a view. Only tables can be updated. The statement `update view` is converted to `update table` (possibly with some restrictions).

`order by` is only applied to the rowset returned from a `select`. It doesn't affect the order rows are *accessed* in the *table*, but your update statement is sensitive to *access* order.

Comment: Each database impose slighly different restrictions to update views. It's possible to do so, if the view is considered "updatable" by the engine.

Answer (score -2):

[Create View](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html)

*CREATE VIEW defines a view of a query. The view is not physically materialized. Instead, the query is run every time the view is referenced in a query.*

```
create table order_test(id integer, fld_1 varchar);

insert into order_test values (1, 'dog'), (2, 'fish'), (3, 'cat');

select * from order_test;
 id | fld_1 
----+-------
  1 | dog
  2 | fish
  3 | cat
(3 rows)

create view vw_order_test as select * from order_test order by fld_1;

select * from vw_order_test ;
 id | fld_1 
----+-------
  3 | cat
  1 | dog
  2 | fish
(3 rows)

insert into order_test values (4, 'aardvark');

select * from order_test;
 id |  fld_1   
----+----------
  1 | dog
  2 | fish
  3 | cat
  4 | aardvark


select * from vw_order_test ;
 id |  fld_1   
----+----------
  4 | aardvark
  3 | cat
  1 | dog
  2 | fish
```

The ordering is honored.

**UPDATE**

```
create table big_table(id integer, fld_1 numeric);

insert into big_table select a, random() * 1000 from generate_series(1, 100000) as t(a);

  id   |        fld_1        
--------+---------------------
      1 |    763.817657064134
      2 |    980.199684623081
      3 |    244.682555561287
      4 |    643.861135921256
      5 |    144.942847930761
...

99996 |    230.111102236449
  99997 |    127.037526956709
  99998 |    66.7148919657663
  99999 |    749.832473831365
 100000 |    504.281936762339


create view vw_big_table as select * from big_table order by fld_1;

  id   |        fld_1        
--------+---------------------
   4858 | 0.00708054987086371
  68190 |  0.0139485327323996
  45454 |     0.0247458957503
  92812 |  0.0274875299197674

...

 22411 |    999.978586972237
  55171 |    999.980785632108
  44598 |    999.987221914829
  30712 |    999.993384242487
  18883 |     999.99984164636

explain select * from vw_big_table ;
                               QUERY PLAN                               
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=9854.82..10104.82 rows=100000 width=15)
   Sort Key: big_table.fld_1
   ->  Seq Scan on big_table  (cost=0.00..1550.00 rows=100000 width=15)
```

This remains the same if I go to 1000000 rows or 10000000 rows.

Comment: The ordering is not honored. Any ordering you see may be considered only as an anecdote.